# Using WHERE in String selection from SQLITE?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need your help please with this code..

I want to search for any name WHERE FIELD_CURRENCY = dollar 
result will be select only names which currency equals to dollar.

```
    private static final String FIELD_ID = "_id";
private static final String FIELD_NAME = "name";
private static final String FIELD_FLAG = "flag";
private static final String FIELD_TEL = "tel";
private static final String FIELD_CURRENCY = "currency";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "countries";

    /** Returns Countries */
public Cursor getCountries(String[] selectionArgs) {

    String selection = FIELD_NAME + " like ?";

    if (selectionArgs != null) {
        selectionArgs[0] = "%" + selectionArgs[0] + "%";
```

My Table :

```
   public class Country {

    // Array of strings storing country names
static String[] countries = new String[] { "India", "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka", "China", "test", "Nepal", "Taza",
        "Test", "test2", "Japan" };

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable
static int[] flags = new int[] { R.drawable.india, R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.japan, R.drawable.china, R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.japan, R.drawable.afghanistan, R.drawable.japan,
        R.drawable.japan, R.drawable.japan  };

// Array of strings to store currencies
static String[] tel = new String[] { "0515155",
            "054545454", "045154", "0154645",
            "054685", "07700125", "0750",
            "07540", "07540", "07540" };

// Array of strings to store currencies
static String[] currency = new String[] { "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee", "Sri Lankan Rupee", "Renminbi",
        "dollar", "Nepalese Rupee", "Afghani",
        "dollar", "South Korean Won", "dollar"  };
```

}
        }
I appreciate your help...

Comment: `Select currency from countries where currency like '%doller%';` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, add it to your selection:

```
String selection = FIELD_NAME + " like ? AND " + FIELD_CURRENCY + "='dollar'";
```

Comment: Thanks laalto for your help, but it says Syntax error on token "FIELD_CURRENCY", delete this token

Comment: Consider adding some detail to the question, such as what your data actually looks like.

Comment: I'm follow this tutorial [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-custom-search-suggestions-to-search-dialog-from-sqlite-database-in-android/)

Comment: its works now i have uninstall and reinstall it works...thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name FROM countries WHERE currency='dollar'